# How to test redirect location with reverse routing?

Tags: scala, testing, playframework-2.0, specs2

How can I test if a controller redirects to a specific location using the reverse routing in play framework 2.3? I would like to do something like this:

```
  "LoginController#authenticate" should{
      "Redirect to index on success" in{
          ...
          val result = loginControllerTest.authenticate.apply(request)
          redirectLocation(result) must be(routes.Application.index)
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`routes.Application.index` is a `Call` which holds a `method` (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE)  and a `url`.

`redirectLocation(result)` returns an `Option[String]` (`None` if there is no redirect)

You would want something like:

```
redirectLocation(result) must beSome(routes.Application.index.url)
```

`routes.Application.index.toString` would do the same.